# Not showing next/previous button using IQKeyboardManagerSwift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, iqkeyboardmanager

I am using IQKeyboardManagerSwift in my application. I can not see next/previous button to toolbar. I attached screen shots of my aliments.

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = true
IQKeyboardManager.shared.toolbarPreviousNextAllowedClasses = [UIView.self, UIStackView.self]
```

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 15):

IQKeyboardManager's `Next/Previous` button doesn't work on `input fields` if they are inside multiple subviews.

Assign `self.view` of `IQPreviousNextView` class from storyboard. It will start working.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it's working for me and it's saved my time. :)

Comment: BhavsangJam & @MiTalKhandhar happy coding :)

Comment: what if you are doing all in programatic layouts

Comment: I have made customView for textFields and I have already given class to these  textFields, how do I give IQPreviousNextView class ?