# IQKeyboard not showing next/previous options inside stackview

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview, xcode10, iqkeyboardmanager

I am not able to see the next/previous button in toolbar using IQKeyboardManagerSwift when its inside stack view I have checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430621/not-showing-next-previous-button-using-iqkeyboardmanagerswift) and added IQPreviousNextView as my view class. But still facing the same issue. Below is my storyboard layout.

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the instructions from `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` GitHub repo: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/wiki/Manual-Management

Embed the `New Pin Stack` in a `UIView`, then assign the custom class of that view to `IQPreviousNextView`

Prior to embedding (Prev / Next arrows not shown):

[image]

After embedding (Prev / Next arrows ***will be shown***):

[image]

[image]

Note: constrain `New Pin Stack` at `0` to all four sides of the new view it is embedded in.

Answer (score 0):

IQPreviousNextView at root view
Do not forget select IQKeyboardSwift at Module

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.